# Vue & LoDash: Toggling Active Tab not working

Tags: vuejs2, lodash

I have an array of auctions with each element looking like this (significantly shortened for question purpose)

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'N782AM',
    is_active: true
}
```

I have a button bar of buttons like this

```
<button
    v-for="(tab, idx) in auctions"
    class="button tab-button"
    :key="tab.id"
    :class="{ active: tab.is_active}"
    @click="toggleTab(idx)">
    {{ tab.title }}
</button>
```

The method toggleTab() is this

```
toggleTab(idx) {
    _.forEach(this.auctions, (a) => a.is_active = false);

    this.auctions[idx].is_active = true;
}
```

++++UPDATED++++
As suggested I changed toggleTab as below

```
toggleTab(idx) {
   _.forEach(this.auctions, (a) => a.is_active = false);

   Vue.set(this.auctions[idx].is_active, true);
}
```

this results in this error:

> vue.common.js?2371:1037 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator
>   to search for 'VN-A566' in N-782AM

++++UPDATED++++

My expectation is that when clicked, the clicked tab should be assigned the active class and turn blue and all other tabs should have the active class removed but nothing is happening.

Comment: reactivity problem. use Vue.set

Comment: thanks, Jacob. Please see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common reactivity problem. using Vue.set would solve it.

[Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) has 3 params. `Vue.set( target, key, value )`

This is an example of how to use it in the method

```
toggleTab(idx) {
  _.forEach(this.auctions, (a, i) =>
    this.$set(this.auctions[i], "is_active", false)
  );

  this.$set(this.auctions[idx], "is_active", true);
}
```

Learn more in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html